# Phonegap iOS Basic Http Authentication

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Trying to do an ajax with http basic authentication on PhoneGap 2.9.
I got it working with Android easily, stuck on iOS for 10 hours and still haven't figured it out.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: path,
            cache: false,
            headers: {"Authorization": credential}
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.debug("testCredential success:    " + data);
            _private.login_successful(username, credential);

        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.debug("textStatus: " + textStatus);
            console.debug("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
            _private.login_failed(path + " - " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
        }).always(function () {
        });
```

The credential is just (Just in case you are wondering):

```
  var tok = username + ':' + password;
  var hash = btoa(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
```

I have tried beforeSend as well, it works for Android as well, but still doesn't work for iOS.

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", credential);}
```

The error I get from textStatus is "error" and nothing from errorThrown.
I tried both http and https url too since I have both, and it didn't matter.
I tried `<access origin="*"/>`, but it didn't matter.
Also I use windows intellij to write the app, so I can't do more testing by writing iOS classes in xcode.

Thanks for your help.

Additional note:
It works if I connect to a non authenticated version of the same site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for trying to help.

I tried Dawson's suggestion, but it didn't work for me, so I switched back.
After 2 days of troubleshooting, I gave up.  So I downloaded ipa from https://build.phonegap.com instead of using Hydration for doing another task, and I installed it through iTunes, then it works.

Answer (score 2):

With the jQuery `ajax` method you can now pass `username` and `password` as parameters and don't need to do anything with the headers.

Try this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: path,
        cache: false,
        username: username,
        password: password
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.debug("testCredential success:    " + data);
        _private.login_successful(username, credential);

    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.debug("textStatus: " + textStatus);
        console.debug("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        _private.login_failed(path + " - " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
    }).always(function () {
    });
```

Here is an example that I have in an application working on both platforms. Note that I use `$.ajaxSetup`:

```
setupAjaxDefaults: function() {
    var headers = {
        'Accept': "application/json; encoding='utf-8'",
        'Content-Type': "application/json; encoding='utf-8'"
    };
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: headers,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        username: 'someuser',
        password: 'somepass',
        crossDomain: true
    });
},
ajaxGet: function(methodName, data, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: api.connection.baseUrl + api.connection.apiUrl + methodName,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result, status, xhr) {
            if ($.isFunction(successCallback)) {
                successCallback(result);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            if ($.isFunction(errorCallback)) {
                errorCallback();
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.
I also tried the username and password, it doesn't work on both iOS and Android.

Comment: Interesting, I have used it in an application before on both platforms. I will dig up my code and add it to my answer.

Comment: Did your usernames have @ symbols in them... Having a very strange when they do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261345/jquery-ajax-fails-when-basic-auth-username-has-symbol-ios-cordova