# Jquery .ajax fails when basic auth username has @ symbol (ios / cordova)

Tags: jquery, rest, cordova, basic-authentication

I have a phonegap app w/ jQuery 1.9.1
Worked great as long as the username doesn't have '@' symbol in it (like in email addresses).
It only fails on iOS.

I suspect it's probably not urlencoding the @ sign or something.

- *iPhone*, ***it never hits any callbacks (done, fail or always), Wireshark shows request doesn't get to the server***.
- *Chrome Desktop*: works fine.
- *Android*, works fine.

  ```
   $.ajax({
          url: "https://" + this.hostname + "/alertusmw/services/rest/" + endPoint,
          type: method,
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/com.alertus-v1.0+json',
          cache:false,
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password,
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
                  "Basic " + $.base64.encode(this.username + ":" + this.password));
          },
          data: options.data
      }).done(function(response) {
          console.log("DONE: " + method + ' completed: ');
          console.log(response);
          options.success( response );
      })
      .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("FAIL: " + method + " FAILED: " + textStatus + "\n" + "ERROR THROWN: " + errorThrown);
          console.log("jqXHR thing: ", jqXHR);
          options.error(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown);
      })
      .always(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("In the always", jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
      });
  ```

  - Verified the base64 header is identical on iphone and chrome desktop.
  - It's not an ssl cert issue.
  - It's not a cors issue
  - It's not an invalid user/pass

Again works perfectly if username doesn't have an '@'

The reason I suspect it's something with url encoding is if it was posting it as:
`https://user@domain:password@blah.domain.com`, the browser wouldn't probably include the `domain:password` part as the host (since the first @ is what separates user:pass from the domain...

Here's what clued me in to this:

[image]

^-- I thought the entire point of base64 encoding was exactly to avoid special characters causing issues... so I thought that maybe this was chrome being helpful...

Related SO Posts:
- [Basic Authentication fails in cordova ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860031/basic-authentication-fails-in-cordova-ios) (no answers, slightly different)

Comment: Does it work if you replace the `@` with an `_` ?

Comment: @Tomanow why would that work? haven't tried... but i'm pretty sure usernames with _ are fine.

Comment: What is `this` in your code snippet? Are you sure it's the same thing on Android and in iOS?

Comment: @Julian, yes it's the same object, it's a wrapper class.  If it was an issue with this then it wouldn't work when it didn't have an @

Comment: Do you really need to specify the beforesend part? With username, password, should be enough. Did you tried to specify a header in the beforesend like this one `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`?

Comment: You're setting the `Authorization` request header yourself, plus adding `username` and `password`, which are (I think) for the same purpose. Have you tried using either the one or the other on their own?

Comment: @geert3 Yah, definitely looks superfluous, I want to say I added the beforeSend because it didn't work on android without it.  I just tried each on it's own on iOS and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I would bet the problem is not using a `contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

Anyway, you should definitely debug your Webview against a real device, to look for xhr errors on the Safari console. If you are not familiar with Safari remote debugging, it's easy:

- in your iPhone/iPad, go to Settings -> Safari -> Advanced => Enable Web Inspector.
- connect to MacOSX via cable, and select your app from the "Develop" menu of Safari in your desktop
- Now check any errors regarding your request, or better yet, debug the code and callbacks step by step.

Comment: No difference with x-www-form-urlencoded, +1 for the webview suggestion, I can now confirm that no uncaught exceptions (or even caught exceptions) are occurring now.  And it never even starts a network request when the @ is present.

Comment: @blak3r mmm... other toughts: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings regarding beforeSend: "Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request", please execute the "$.base64.encode" call in a different line as a variable and log it, to make sure it's not returning false for some crazy reason.

Comment: @blak3r also, calling the "beforeSend" it's completely necessary? Can you try to fill the "headers (default: {})" object of settings instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping encodeURIComponent() before base64 encoding.

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
            "Basic " + $.base64.encode(encodeURIComponent(this.username + ":" + this.password)));
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

When base64encoded text is UNencoded on the other end, it still looks like (as you said), `user@domain:password@blah.domain.com` Try having a function like this:

```
var getAuthToken = function (user, pass) {
    var token = "";
    if (user) {
        token = token + encodeURIComponent(user);
    }
    if (pass) {
        token = token + ":" + encodeURIComponent(pass);
    }
    token = $.base64.encode(token);
    return "Basic " + token;
};
```

Then just change your code slightly:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", getAuthToken(this.username, this.password));
```